# Getting started with a blacklist

Tags: security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I blacklisted "213.5.64.179" and wonder if you can recommend how to proceed?
Should I do this on an ad-hoc basis just following the instructions and blacklist bad hosts as we go along or take precaution now knowing one, thinking that knowing one ("213.5.64.179") could increase awareness whether to block an entire net or other actions. Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: What operating system/platform are you using?

Comment: the tag says google-app-engine.

Comment: It's google app engine (dos.yaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest going with the ad-hoc plan unless you have a business requirement to black out a well defined portion of the internet. Rarely will hack attempts come from a well defined subnet because its too easy to block an entire range of addresses. Attempts are likely to come through zombie proxies with widely distributed addresses.

The other problem is that the limit is 100 entries. Not enough to defeat a determined attempt. Probably likely enough to block the script kiddies coming from home.

BTW, you don't have to worry about china or turkey as sources. ghs.google.com is blocked at their firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

On *nix operating systems you can blaklist an ip address with iptables:

`iptables -A FIREWALL -i eth1 -s 213.5.64.179 -j DROP`

Comment: Rook, this question is not about unix.  it is about google-app-engine.

Comment: @Peter the op added more info.